# Как добавить свой скрипт на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, greasemonkey

Допустим при просмотре какого-то постороннего сайта, можно ли добавить свой js-скрипт и ajax-запрос к своему php-скрипту?
т.е. если нет вообще доступа к этому сайту.
Это нужно к примеру, чтобы при просмотре страниц, сделать чтобы скрипт делал определённую рутинную работу на этом сайте

Comment: можно через консоль

Comment: @Duoxx, а при переходе на другую страницу, этот новый js-скрипт останется? т.е. если только через консоль

Comment: нет но тогда только через tampermonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, расширение позволяет внедрять собственные скрипты: 
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ru)

Пример скриптов можно найти по тегу [greasemonkey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) - так назывался предок всех подобных расширений.

Comment: Аналоги есть и для других браузеров.